# How do i organize these images in html

Tags: html, css

so this is my code and i want the 4 images that are named (team 1,team2,team3,team4) to be at the bottom next to each other not on top
this is the code everythins is fine but i just dont know how to position the images correctly
is there any way to fix this? maybe i could put them in a different section?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.images {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.images img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.images input {
    display: none;
}
.dots {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid #FFCCCC 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label:hover {background: #fff;}
#img1:checked ~ .m1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#img2:checked ~ .m2 {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
#img3:checked ~ .m3 {
    margin-left: -200%;
}
#img4:checked ~ .m4 {
    margin-left: -300%;
};
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.images {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.images img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.images input {
    display: none;
}
.dots {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid #FFCCCC 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label:hover {background: #FFCCCC;}
#img1:checked ~ .m1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#img2:checked ~ .m2 {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
#img3:checked ~ .m3 {
    margin-left: -200%;
}
#img4:checked ~ .m4 {
    margin-left: -300%;
}


* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Container needed to position the overlay. Adjust the width as needed */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 57%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* Make the image to responsive */
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* The overlay effect - lays on top of the container and over the image */
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* When you mouse over the container, fade in the overlay title */
.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="images">
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img1" checked>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img2">
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img3">
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img4">

            <img src="1.jpg" class="m1" alt="img1">
            <img src="2.jpeg" class="m2" alt="img2">
            <img src="3.jpeg" class="m3" alt="img3">
            <img src="4.jpeg" class="m4" alt="img4">
        </div>
        <div class="dots">
            <label for="img1"></label>
            <label for="img2"></label>
            <label for="img3"></label>
            <label for="img4"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    

        <div class="container">

  <img src="team1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
</div>

    <div class="container">

  <img src="team2.jpg"  alt="Avatar" class="image" >
  
  <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
</div>

    <div class="container">

  <img src="team3.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
</div>

    <div class="container">

  <img src="team4.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `justify-content: center;` by `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    background: * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.images {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.images img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.images input {
    display: none;
}
.dots {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid #FFCCCC 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label:hover {background: #fff;}
#img1:checked ~ .m1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#img2:checked ~ .m2 {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
#img3:checked ~ .m3 {
    margin-left: -200%;
}
#img4:checked ~ .m4 {
    margin-left: -300%;
};
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.images {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.images img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.images input {
    display: none;
}
.dots {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid #FFCCCC 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dots label:hover {background: #FFCCCC;}
#img1:checked ~ .m1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#img2:checked ~ .m2 {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
#img3:checked ~ .m3 {
    margin-left: -200%;
}
#img4:checked ~ .m4 {
    margin-left: -300%;
}


* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Container needed to position the overlay. Adjust the width as needed */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 57%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* Make the image to responsive */
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* The overlay effect - lays on top of the container and over the image */
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* When you mouse over the container, fade in the overlay title */
.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="images">
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img1" checked>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img2">
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img3">
            <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img4">

            <img src="1.jpg" class="m1" alt="img1">
            <img src="2.jpeg" class="m2" alt="img2">
            <img src="3.jpeg" class="m3" alt="img3">
            <img src="4.jpeg" class="m4" alt="img4">
        </div>
        <div class="dots">
            <label for="img1"></label>
            <label for="img2"></label>
            <label for="img3"></label>
            <label for="img4"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <img src="team1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <img src="team2.jpg"  alt="Avatar" class="image" >
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <img src="team3.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <img src="team4.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```